# Is there is any limit to the number of siddhi apps that can be deployed on WSO2 Stream Processor 4.0

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

Is there is any limit to the number of siddhi apps that can be deployed on WSO2 Stream Processor 4.0? What factors determine the limit on the number of apps?

Comment: What did you mean by "rules"? Business Rules or Siddhi Apps?

Comment: Siddhi apps encapsulating rules on streaming events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no hard and fast rules for determining the limit on the number of apps. The main factors you should consider is the memory consumption and CPU consumption of each app. The number of in-memory stores, the complexity of patterns, Event TPS, Event sizes, etc... will affect that memory consumption and CPU consumption factors.